# unwrap ldifde output file

Tags: perl, active-directory, ldif

I'm exporting a schema using ldifde but the output file wraps long lines so it's hard to manually edit with thousand's lines.

I have to edit the file because I must replace a string there, for example:

```
distinguishedName: 
 CN=xxx-com-Admin-Assistant-yy,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,-->DC=morel,DC=mis,DC=mo
 r-ambiguit,<--DC=com
```

to

```
distinguishedName: 
 CN=xxx-com-Admin-Assistant-yy,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,-->DC=myDomain,<--DC=com
```

As you can see I should first unwrap the file and then replace the string, otherwise the replace won't work Any clues on how I should perform that. I tried perl script but not luck. Also I looked into ldifde options.

Thank in advance,
m0dest0

Comment: @dgw c:\Perl64\bin>perl -p -e "BEGIN {$/ = undef}    s/\n(?=[a-z])/ /g" test.ldf

Comment: @dgw c:\Perl64\bin>perl -p -e "s/\n //g" test.ldf

Comment: And the `-->` `<--` should help finding the changes or are they part of the data?

Comment: You're trying to remove `DC=morel,DC=mis,DC=mor-ambiguit,` with that perl regex? How was that supposed to work?

Comment: @dgw Thank you, your script runs very well.

Comment: @JPBlanc, using the c option from ldifde, the perl script was not needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you strictly want to import the schema from one domain to another using LDIFDE, you can use the `-c` parameter from LDIFDE to change one DN to another, see [KB237677: Using LDIFDE to import and export directory objects to Active Directory](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237677/en-us).

```
-c FromDN ToDN  Replace occurrences of FromDN to ToDN
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;

my $orig = do { local $/ ; <DATA> } ;
( my $copy = $orig ) =~ s/(DC=)(.+?)(,DC=com)/$1myDomain$3/xsg ;

printf "Before:\n%s\nAfter:\n%s\n" , $orig , $copy ;

__DATA__
distinguishedName:
 CN=xxx-com-Admin-Assistant-yy,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=morel,DC=mis,DC=mo
 r-ambiguit,DC=com
```

And this will print:

```
Before:
distinguishedName:
 CN=xxx-com-Admin-Assistant-yy,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=morel,DC=mis,DC=mo
 r-ambiguit,DC=com

After:
distinguishedName:
 CN=xxx-com-Admin-Assistant-yy,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=myDomain,DC=com
```